# SSIS 2008 looping over flat files with different layout

Tags: file, loops, ssis, flat

Does anybody already faced an issue when trying to import FF (with not always the same number of column) through a loop into a DB ?
Indeed my DB has been created with the maximal number of columns that a FF can have so the problem is not here but at the Flat file source component.
How can I configure the FF source to consider at every loop each columns of the file treated? 
I always get this can of error when looping on a FF with less column that define at the FF Connection manager  : [Flat File Source [1]] Error: The column delimiter for column "Column xx" was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the metadata for the file (column number & types) is evaluated at the start of the package run rather than each loop. I don't believe that there is any way to change this.

The only suggestion I can make is to implement a custom file reader as a script component that populates the correct subset of the superset of possible columns. I've implemented something similar in the past and this works well.